# Authors in two columns for IEEEcsmag.cls

Tags: latex, .class-file

In IEEEcsmag.cls template for an IEEE magazine, authors can be added as follows (default).

```
\documentclass{IEEEcsmag}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{upmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Title:...}

\author{F. A. Author}
\affil{First Affiliation}

\author{S. B. Author, Jr.}
\affil{Second Affiliation}

\author{T. C. Author, III}
\affil{Third Affiliation}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I need to add multiple authors in two columns but unable to find a proper solution.
Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: If you plan to submit to the journal, use their layout and don't change it

Comment: Can you add a link to the version of `IEEEcsmag.cls` you are using?